# retrieve all fields with a specific name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how do I retrieve all latitudes and longitudes under all the keys?
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6sat.png)
I tried this but no work:

```
                            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    String text = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
                                    System.out.println(text);

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
```

I want to print:

```
40.7486720036497

-73.9856280013919
```

etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to get the list of latitutudes and longitudes from your firebase like this -

```
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override 
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         String keys=datas.getKey(); 
         String latitudes=datas.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
         String location=datas.child("location").getValue().toString();
         String longitude=datas.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
      } 
    }
 });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use model class approach?
Create your own custom class

```
public class ModelClass {
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public ModelClass(String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Then while inserting data, insert like this.

```
ModelClass mc=new ModelClass("1.23","3.25");//You pass dynamic value here using variable
String key=mref.push().getKey();
myRef.child(key).setValue(mc);
```

Then read the value like this.

```
List<ModelClass> list=new ArrayList<>();
  myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for(DataSnapShot ds:dataSnapShot){
                                  ModelClass mc=ds.getValue(ModelClass.class);
                                  list.add(mc);
                                  }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
```

Then you can work with the list of data.
For more reference [see the docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data).